# How to get multiple values from a single <select> variable in HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, select

Alright, so what I have is a standard **select option** in an HTML form, but what I'm trying to do is send over multiple values to the receiving PHP script from a single **option value**.

Such as something like this (I know it's incorrect):

```
<select name="size" id="size" type="text">
<option value="3" value="5" >3 Inches by 5 Inches</option>
<option value="6" value="4" >6 Inches by 4 Inches</option>
<option value="8" value="10" >8 Inches by 10 Inches</option>
</select>
```

And then on the receiving PHP script it would perhaps get some sort of "size[1], size[2]" or something. If anybody knows how to do this, any help would be terrific. I've searched around quite extensively, but I haven't seen anything quite like this. Thanks again!

Comment: `<select name="size" id="size" type="text" multiple="multiple">`

Comment: Why not just use `value="3x5"`, `value="6x4"`, etc.?

Comment: perhaps checkboxes would be better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can pass the two values in the value

```
<select name="size" id="size" type="text">
    ....
    <option value="6x4" >6 Inches by 4 Inches</option>
</select>
```

and in the backend you can split it to get the value

```
list($x,$y) = explode("x",$_GET['size']);  // or POST

echo $x; // 6
echo $y; // 4
```

Comment: +1 This is the sane way. Alternatively you *could* use an array field name (eg: `sizes[]`) and use JS to assign multiple values to it upon selecting one of them. But this probably isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: @NullUserException you are correct, if javascript is used this is a good solution too

Comment: Terrific, thank you for the tips. Anyhow, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much Ibu!

Comment: @Aaron im glad i could help, one suggestion though would be to make sure to check the values of parameters in the POST or GET before using them.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a separator character within your value attribute?

```
<option value="3_5" >3 Inches by 5 Inches</option>
```

Now when you come to examine those values in PHP, you can simply use `explode()` on the value to extract both of them.

```
$sizes = explode('_',$_POST['size']);
```

You'll now have an array containing the separated values -

```
array (
  0 => '3',
  1 => '5',
)
```

In this example, I have chosen the underscore `_` character as my separator but you could use any character you want.

Reference -

- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! I'll be marking the answer from Ibu as correct only because he has the output list with variables which is how I would prefer it. Thank you very much for the time.

Comment: @aar - no worries :) Happy to help! In my experience, using the `list` command leaves you more prone to mistakes but its your project and not mine in this case :)