# Post multiple values from database, in one Option

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am looking to populate a drop down field with a list of names from a database, and when an option is selected from that drop down, it will post all its values in the row, belonging to that chosen option.

This is probably hard to describe/understand, so to help illustrate, this is my table row:

[image: db structure]

I then proceed to populate the dropdown, and  associate its value to whatever the selected option is posted

```
//////db_conx is db connection //////main_meal is table name
      <form action="#" method="post">
                        <?php  
                        $dropdown = $db_conx->query("SELECT * FROM main_meal") or die ("somethings broken");                       
                        while($array[] = $dropdown->fetch_object());
                        //echo '<option value ="'.$record['Mname'].'">'.$record['Mname'].'"</option>';                        
                        array_pop($array);                       
                        ?>

                        <select name="changeCal">
                            <?php    foreach($array as $option) :?>
                            <!--//get chosen value in drop down, and get its calories-->
                            <option value="<?php echo $option->calories;?>"><?php echo $option->Mname; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
```

This works great for one value, such as calories, in the above code, but I need more values.

For example, if choose Healthy egg and chips, the value will post 218, as the loop only associates calories and names at the moment.

I attempted various things, like this post:[How to get multiple values from a single <select> variable in HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791021/how-to-get-multiple-values-from-a-single-select-variable-in-html-php)

But the foreach errors.

How can I something similar to what I have done, but store multiple values from one chosen option?

Thank you

Comment: Have it send the `id`. Then you can look up all the values in the database using the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I understood your problem, but I think that the way you want to use is not usable, maybe I recommend that you put the id in the value of the option in the < select> and then with php you can get all the data from the data base.
For me that is the best way, but if you want do it like the example that you show, you can make an string, for example:

```
<option value="id:5_calories:258_protein:11g">Healthy eggs & Chips</option>
```

with your php should look like:

```
echo '<option value="id:'.$option->id.'_calories:'.$option->calories.'_protein:'.$option->protein.'">'.$option->Mname.'</option>';
```

you can make bigger the string with others values that you want to put.
In the backend when you send the select you can catch the data with a:

```
$myArray = explode("_", $_POST["changeCal"]);
```

Then you will get an array with values like:

```
$myArray[0]; // id:5
$myArray[1]; // calories:258
$myArray[2]; // protein:11g
```

Then if you need for example the calories you can make an explode like:

```
   $calories = explode(":",$myArray[1]);
```

And you will have:

```
   $calories[0]; //calories
   $calories[1]; //258   <= Here are the calories.
```

Maybe if you want to do it of that way, this can be the easiest way, but I recommend send the ID.

Let me know if you need more help. Regards, Have a nice day.